# How to enable MySQL query log in "Server version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)" on to server?

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql-5.5

I'm using MySQL database server **("Server version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)")** using **phpMyAdmin**.

I'm using **PHP** as a server-side language which communicates with the database by means of SQL queries.

I want to add the log of all the queries that are basically called from the PHP code.

I did lot of research on this issue and gone through various similar questions on SO but still I'm confused because all those questions and answers are quite old(posted way back around 6-7 years).

So I want the latest,reliable and best solution for the current situation.

Though let me tell you few specific things on my server in order to understand my problem better and provide me the best possible solution.

First of all I checked whether the query log is enabled in a file **my.cnf** **(location on server : /etc/mysql/my.cnf)**

The file content is as follows :

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Let me know what code I need to add in order to enable the query log.

If you have some other easier and safer way to enable the query log you can explain me.

Now I came to know that after making the change to the file and uploading the file **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** the MySQL server has to be restarted in order to take the new change effect. How should I restart it?

If there is no need to restart the server then it's ok.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is written inside the config file

```
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
```

just uncomment `general_log_file` and `general_log` lines and restart mysql.

You can enable the log in runtime with a query, without a mysql restart:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but please let me know how to re-start mysql? It would be of great help to me man.

Comment: on ubuntu you need to issue this command in a console: `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: The database is not located on my local machine, it's on remote server. So in this case should I use the same command to restart the server?

Comment: You need do restart the service on the machine that is running it. If the remote machine is an ubuntu 12.* or 14.* the command to run is the same as above